# How to avoid double hand shake serverClient/clientServer connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, networking, bonjour

I have written a client server app that connect two iphones using bonjour. My problems is that when both devices start broadcasting and listening using bonjour they find each other at the same moment and both of them connect as a client of each other. How can I avoid this scenario? I am already checking if my app is connected as a server to the other app, but since that happens simultaneously I always connect as a server and client at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

looking into  ur case ;  1 solution is that u  can make ur device on which app is hosted and gotta serve as server make that devices tcb as passive open so it can only listen on particular port/frequency and client can be programed to be in active open state so it can send request to server.